# subsetting data using multiple variables in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a data set, DATA, with many variables. DATA has a list mode and its class is a data.frame.
The variables I'm concerned with are AGE.MONTHS and LOCATION. I need to subset DATA into another set called SUB, and I want SUB to only contain the observations where AGE.MONTHS <= 2 and LOCATION = "Area A". AGE.MONTHS is has a numeric mode and class. LOCATION has a numeric mode and its class is a factor. I have tried the following,

```
SUB<-which((DATA$AGE.MONTHS <= 2 )& (DATA$LOCATION=="Area A"))
```

But this only tells me which observations these conditions hold true for, and what I need is a subset of all the data for which these conditions hold.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `subset` function.

```
subset(DATA, AGE.MONTHS <= 2 & LOCATION == "Area A")
```

Comment: Ha, thanks! I'm actually a bit embarrassed I didn't come to this myself!

Comment: Nothing to be embarrassed about :). R does have a stepper learning curve than some other languages, but it's very powerful once you learn it.

Comment: I tried subset, but using this code: SUB<-subset(DATA, subset=AGE>MONTHS<=2 and subset=LOCATION=="Area A").[which is straight out of the R manual, BTW] When it didn't work, I just thought it wasn't the right thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

If this is in a program, you are better to use `[` than subset.  For example, see here: [Why is `[` better than `subset`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset)

To subset with `[`, you want this:

```
DATA[with(DATA, AGE.MONTHS <= 2 & LOCATION == "Area A"), ]
```